# Multiple buttons not working in a form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a form such that the user can enter HTML code in the textarea which can be rendered when the Preview button is clicked and submitted to the database when the Submit button is clicked. But the data is being submitted when the preview button is clicked.

HTML Code:

```js
function parse() {
  var html = document.getElementById("ta").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<form action="/admin/pages/add-page" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Content</label>
    <textarea name="content" class="form-control" id="ta" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="content"><%= content %></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" onclick="parse()">Preview</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
<br><br>
<h2>HTML output:</h2>
<div class="float:right" id="result">
```

Comment: did you try to move the preview button out of the form block?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preview button is a submit button!

If you want it to be Just For JavaScript, add `type="button"`.

Comment: Probably to add - for semantic/accessibility reason - `type=submit` to submit button.

Comment: @Andreas — Explicitly setting the value of an attribute to its default does nothing to help semantics or accessibility. It just means more code to write and send to the browser.

Comment: Fair enough, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the button's type `type="button"`. If you do not specify the type attribute of a button, it will default to submit, as such it is submitting your form.

[MDN docs on button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Answer (score 2):

In your preview button add a type="button" if you don't added by default the form will treat it as a submit button..

```js
function parse() {
        var html = document.getElementById("ta").value;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html;
    }
```

```html
<form action="/admin/pages/add-page" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Content</label>
        <textarea name="content" class="form-control" id="ta" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="content"><%= content %></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="parse()">Preview</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
<br><br>
<h2>HTML output:</h2>
<div class="float:right" id="result">
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something you're missing, you haven't included your `type` which should be `type="button"`, i.e

`<button class="btn" type="button" onclick="parse()">Preview</button>`.

You will need to include it between the preview button tag.

Which should make you new code look like the one below.

```
function parse() {
  var html = document.getElementById("ta").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html;
}
```

---

```
<form action="/admin/pages/add-page" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Content</label>
        <textarea name="content" class="form-control" id="ta" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="content"><%= content %></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="parse()">Preview</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
    <br><br>
    <h2>HTML output:</h2>
    <div class="float:right" id="result">
```

This should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change Button type in your code like:

```
<form action="/admin/pages/add-page" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Content</label>
        <textarea name="content" class="form-control" id="ta" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="content"><%= content %></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="parse()">Preview</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
<br><br>
<h2>HTML output:</h2>
<div class="float:right" id="result">
<script>
    function parse() {
        var html = document.getElementById("ta").value;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html;
    }
</script>
```